# CiviCRM Training resources?

Tags: tutorials

Hi does anyone have access to any training videos or material for civicrm? For example, Admin and database reporting, user training, etc.

Thanks in advance

Edward

Comment: Please have a look on a similar question [here](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10536/civicrm-training-courses-for-beginners)

Answer (score 11):

For a free option, you can also look to past CiviCRM conferences.  A lot of presenters upload their notes to the session pages.  Videos are often posted as well.  The videos for the most recent conference in Denver are now available: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjSU7YfE0E01HW7JPVAI80XDI0sgOSPDs. There are helpful notes already posted on the session pages.

https://denver2015.civicrm.org/sessions

https://london2013.civicrm.org/sessions
https://london2014.civicrm.org/sessions

https://dc2014.civicrm.org/sessions

http://sf2013.civicrm.org/sessions

Comment: Thank You very much Allen for providing valuable training resources

Answer (score 9):

Civiteacher.com is very reasonably priced (especially for a whole team). I've used it since its inception, and it has been helpful across a number of concepts and functions.

Answer (score 7):

This page has resources that you can use to put together 1 or 2 day training courses on the general use and administration of CiviCRM: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Training.  It's designed as a syllabus for someone with experience with CiviCRM to teach others so might not be exactly what you are looking for but it's useful none the less.  It's also used as the basis for a lot of the in person training courses that happen around conferences, etc.

Comment: Great resource,. Thanks you Michaelmcandrew

Answer (score 5):

[Progressive Technology Project](http://progressivetech.org) puts a lot of videos for Powerbase (their branded CiviCRM) [on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE5F8CFD9F95DD6D0).

[Cividesk](https://www.cividesk.com) has a webinar training series - see the [calendar here](https://www.cividesk.com/civicrm/event/ical?reset=1&list=1&html=1).

Comment: Thank you very much Allen  Hutchinson, Jon G, Coleman for responding and providing answers to my questions.